# SQL: PIVOT return all NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

Hello everyone and thanks in advance.
I have two tables that I need to merge using Pivot.

1)Table with list of users:

```
 #Tbl_staff(UserId INT, 
            Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Surname NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Level NVARCHAR (MAX)
            )
```

2) Table with users' actions:

```
#Tbl_acts(Day DATE,
          UserIdfk INT, 
          WorkedHours NVARCHAR(MAX),
          Absence NVARCHAR(MAX),
          Festivity NVARCHAR(2)
          )
```

[image: Example:] 
Table 2 has a complete month for each ID and for each day the action recorded. (Hours worked, hours of absence and type of absence, if the day is a holiday).. 
It can also be null if in the db there is no action for that person on that day.

I wrote my Pivot like this:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N''; 
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME((cast(USERID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ' + NAME+ ' ' + SURNAME+' ' +(ISNULL (LEVEL,''))))
  FROM (SELECT p.USERID,p.NAME,p.SURNAME,p.LEVEL FROM #TBL_STAFF AS p
  INNER JOIN #TBL_ACTS AS o
  ON p.USERID = o.USERIDFK

  GROUP BY p.USERID,P.NAME,P.SURNAME,P.LEVEL) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT  DAY,' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT o.DAY,IDU = CAST(p.USERID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), o.WORKEDHOURS
   FROM #TBL_STAFF AS p, #TBL_ACTS AS o
   where p.USERID= o.USERIDFK
) AS j
PIVOT
(
   MAX(WORKEDHOURS) FOR IDU IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p ORDER BY DAY;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

(Trying to show only the worked hours  ... would be a good start)

It's the result: Column 'day' is ok(31 rows) and 'staff' too but it shows nothing inside it.
[image: Pivot]

Comment: This looks like SQL Server; why have you tagged MySQL?

Comment: `QUOTENAME((cast(USERID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ' + NAME+ ' ' + SURNAME+' ' +(ISNULL (LEVEL,''))))` considering that `NAME`, `SURNAME` and `LEVEL` are an `nvarchar(MAX)` you are saying that that someone's name could be **1 billion~** characters long, and that, with they're surname it could **2 billion~** characters long. `QUOTENAME` accepts the datatype `sysname` and if the value is longer than the maximum length, `NULL` will be returned. I therefore don't suggest that something that could be **3 billion~** characters long will work correctly in the funciton.

Comment: @Larnu Tried something like nvarchar(20) but has not solved the issue.

Comment: What I was suggesting there wasn't a fix, it was an observation of your data and use of `QUOTENAME`.